# Currency converstaion in Quote

Tags: quote, multi-currency, convertcurrency

If I have a product in USD and wanted to quote it in INR, it would do the conversion and put the product in the quote.

is there any possible way to achieve this ?

Comment: You need to a) enable multi-currency, b) define pricebook entries for each product in both USD and INR,  and c) ensure the Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode and Quote.CurrencyIsoCode fields have a vlaue of INR before displaying the quote.

Comment: ok. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your UDS to INR by Multiple Currency -

[Using Multi Currency and Base price for product](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44046/using-multi-currency-and-base-price-for-product?rq=1)

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_currency.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: Do i need to create new currency rate for the same ??